# How to use GSON library on website?

Tags: java, php, json, gson

I was wondering about some system which gets live information from League of Legends game that I can implement to website. I found LEAGUELIB (here is the documentation : https://github.com/achimala/leaguelib) It's GSON-java library but I just don't know to implement this type of library to website, I read that it gets information into JSON but I don't know how. (I know how to get JSON information via PHP from exact page for example. twitch.tv etc. , but this one... nope)

Thanks for your reply and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a PHP expert, but you can maybe take a look to [PHP: Java integration](http://php.net/manual/en/book.java.php)
Good luck with this !

edit: Obviously, you can create a website with java (JavaEE, Spring or Play for example) for a smooth integration of the library, depends on your favorite language.